# Convert .doc, .docx ,.txt into pdf with vb.net

Tags: pdf-generation, vb.net-2010

i have to convert .doc, .docx and .txt file into pdf with the same name, please can you suggest me any api or code that can help me,
help please

Comment: How about [iText](http://itextpdf.com/)?

Comment: i think it's for java? there is any library for .NET !!

Comment: On the front page, it says "iText is available in Java as well as in C#."